# Jquery validating a form and then performing a function

Tags: jquery, function, validation, dom-events

I have the following problem. I wish to validate the form by clicking on the button and if the form is valid make the overlay pop up.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('#submitButton').click( function(){

 if ($("#EnquiryFormContact").checkValidity() ==  true) {
     //If true call here
    //alert("Form is good");

    $("a[rel]").overlay({
        mask: '#000'

})

 }
 else
 {
     //if false call here
  alert("Form is bad");


 }

 //Return False to disable the submit but allow the button to be triggered.
return false;
});

});
```

My code is not that great and I am just learning but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what the question is here.

Comment: 1. Don't forget about the keyboard: what if someone presses enter while the button is focused?

2. What is the question?

Comment: Sorry guys, not explaining myself and rushing. The user clicks on the submit button and then an overlay opens with some other options to be completed these are not validated but optional. If the user does not want to fill them out then they can continue on and submit the form from the overlay. The problem i have is if the overlay opens without validating the form then the overlay will not submit the form as the validation errors show underneath the overlay.

Answer (score 0):

Check the jQuery UI section of this post:
http://www.jensbits.com/2009/08/10/modal-confirmation-dialog-on-form-submit-javascript-jquery-ui-and-thickbox-varieties/

It may point you in the right direction.

Comment: This is something i loked at before Jen, but i need to have form inputs on the overlay as well. These are optional and do not need to be validated when the form is submitted.

Comment: So the overlay is opening whether the form is valid or not? The example in the link gives you all the functionality you need to add your validation. Add your if statement to the submit function and open the dialog if valid. Return false to the submit function so the form does not submit. If not valid, do not open the dialog, just show the errors on the page. If valid, open the dialog with your extra optional fields and have the dialog submit the form.